# Corrupted / orphaned relationships in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I've been trying to do some refactoring work on my database (creating new relationships between nodes to speed up some queries), but caused an out of memory exception because I underestimated the number of nodes (silly Friday afternoon mistake that I'm paying for on Monday). The query didn't finish, but did cause the DB to crash, and a server restart was required.

Now, I'm trying to re-run the query, but it seems some of my data has been corrupted or some nodes have been orphaned (perhaps because the transaction didn't have time to rollback).

Does anyone have experience of this error, or advice on how to go about fixing it?

This is an alpha-semi-prod database for which I have nightly backups (and a very small set of users), and so I'd love not to have to resort to backup and so save data.

*The error I'm encountering:*

```
While loading relationships for Node[1020530] a Relationship[3372448] was encountered that had startNode: 1865693 and endNode: 1769485, i.e. which had neither start nor end node as the node we're loading relationships for
```

*The query (included for the sake of completeness):*

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
  'MATCH (a:Address)-[:IN]->(c:City) WHERE not((a)-[:ADDR_IN_CITY]->(:City)) WITH a, c LIMIT {limit} CREATE (a)-[:ADDR_IN_CITY]->(c) RETURN COUNT(c) as c_count',
  { limit: 1000 }
)
```